# Sort array on two parameters in swift

Tags: arrays, sorting, swift, parameters

I want to sort an array on two parameters, for example, name and then by description.
Sorting the array first by name and then by description won't work because then the array won't be sorted by name.

The solution should be something like this:

```
var sortedArray = sorted(items, { (o1: MyObject, o2: MyObject) -> Bool in
            return o1.name < o2.name and o1.description < o2.description
        })
```

Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your syntax looks correct. Just change the closure to

```
return o1.name == o2.name ? (o1.description < o2.description) : (o1.name < o2.name)
```

If you want more than two sort criteria I recommend using the old fashioned sort descriptors.

```
let sortedArray = (unsortedArray as NSArray).sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([
  NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true),
  NSSortDescriptor(key: "description", ascending: true),
  .... 
]) as! [Object]
```

Comment: So that it sorts first on name and then on description. Otherwise it sorts on both keys at the same time.

Comment: There is no repetition. It should sort by `name` (part 3), and only by `description` (part 2) when the names are equal (part 1).

Comment: can you please tell me the way to have a third sort filter in the list? can get it to work only for two

Comment: Perhaps you should ask a new SOF question.